# Adding a time counter in Java?

Tags: java, timer, counter

I am writing an application in Java and I would like to add a counter in it that the user can start and stop. It would count in second and then go to minutes and up to hours (not days or months). What would I do to make something like this?

Here is how it would function:

1. User clicks 'start'
2. Counter starts...
3. User clicks 'pause'
4. Counter stops but doesn't reset

I am new to Java so is there any code that I could look at that does this or something similar to this? If not could someone write me a little code to get me started with this?

Thanks,
Ljbaumer

Answer (score 2):

Some recommendations:

- I would use Swing for my GUI library
- I would use a Swing Timer as the nucleus of the GUI timer.
- A JLabel would display the change in time from the Swing Timer.
- The start JButton's ActionListener would start the Swing Timer (calling `start()` on it)
- The pause JButton's ActionListener would call `stop()`.

Regarding:

> I am new to Java so is there any code that I could look at that does this or something similar to this? If not could someone write me a little code to get me started with this?

No, that's not how it works here. You are responsible for writing your own code, but we'll be glad to help you along if you get stuck or run into any errors or exceptions. You will learn much more by forcing your brain to create the code, especially if it seems difficult to do.

Please check out the following tutorials:

- [Using Swing Components Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)
- [Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Swing JButton Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [How to Write an ActionListener Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

Someone mentioned the Guava StopWatch class.  I'm not sure if you can pause and resume with that, but I know apache commons-lang has a StopWatch class which does allow this via the suspend() and resume() methods

```
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.start();
...
stopWatch.suspend();
...
stopWatch.resume();
...
stopWatch.stop():

long elapsed = stopWatch.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.nanoTime()` returns the current time, in nanoseconds. Call it once and store the result in a variable, let your program run for a while, call it a second time and compute the difference. You'll get nanoseconds that you may convert to seconds, minutes, or whatever unit you want.

Guava has a [StopWatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) class that does everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

You can set up buttons to start and pause the timer.

This example should help get you started:

Swing/SwingTimeraction.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240_Swing/SwingTimeraction.htm